# Combine strings if they are part of another larger string in the same list

Tags: python, algorithm

Given the list of sentences and the words that may be included in the list, I would like to exclude them from the list, and merge them into the largest string if such exists. Each appearance of the "part" of this largest string should count towards the count of the largest string appearances.

```python
from collections import defaultdict

sentence_parts = ['quick brown', 'brown fox', 'fox', 'lazy dog',
                  'quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog',]

sentences_with_count = defaultdict(int)

for s in sentence_parts:
    matching_sentences = sorted([si for si in sentence_parts if s in si and len(si) > len(s)],
                                key=len, reverse=True)
    if matching_sentences:
        current_sent_count = sentences_with_count.get(s, 1)
        sentences_with_count[matching_sentences[0]] += current_sent_count
    else:
        sentences_with_count[s] += 1

print(sentences_with_count)
```

So the output of `sentences_with_count` will be:

```python
{
    'quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog': 5
}
```

Here's [repl.it](https://repl.it/LoR3/0)

I understand this is not efficient at all. How can I improve it?

Some more examples:

```python
sentence_parts = ['The', 'Ohio State', 'Ohio', 
                  'Paris, France', 'Paris',
                  'The Ohio State University']

>>> {'The Ohio State University': 4, 'Paris, France': 2}

sentence_parts = ['Obama', 'Barack', 'Barack Hussein Obama']

>>> {'Barack Hussein Obama': 3}

sentence_parts = ['Obama', 'Barack', 'Barack Hussein Obama',
                  'Steve', 'Jobs', 'Steve Jobs', 'Mark', 'Bob']

>>> {'Barack Hussein Obama': 3, 'Steve Jobs': 3, 'Mark': 1, 'Bob': 1}
```

Another issue with this approach: If there are multiple matched strings for the substring, only the count of the largest will be incremented:

```python
sentence_parts = ['The', 'The New York City', 'The Voice']
>>> {'The New York City': 2, 'The Voice': 1}
```

Ideally, the output should be `{'The New York City': 2, 'The Voice': 2}`

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat shorter and fixes the issue you described at the end with only the largest being incremented.

```
sentence_parts = ['The', 'Ohio State', 'Ohio', 
              'Paris, France', 'Paris',
              'The Ohio State University']
matching = {key:{'count':1, 'in': False} for key in sentence_parts}

for i in sentence_parts:
    for i2 in sentence_parts:
        if i in i2 and i != i2:
            matching[i2]['count'] += 1
            matching[i]['in'] = True

print({x: matching[x]['count'] for x in matching if not matching[x]['in']})
```

**Edit:** Removed

```
sentence_parts = sorted(sentence_parts, key=len)
```

Because it wasn't necessary

**Edit 2**: Shortened dictionary creation by using list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution splits the problem conceptually into 2 operations,

1. Find actual count of appearance of every sentence.
2. Remove any sentences that is already computed in larger sentences.

This solution is easier to debug and extend in future.

```
from collections import defaultdict

sentence_parts =  ['The', 'Ohio State', 'Ohio',
                   'Paris, France', 'Paris',
                   'The Ohio State University']

sentences_with_count = defaultdict(int)
for part in sentence_parts:
    for sentence in sentence_parts:
        if part in sentence:
            sentences_with_count[sentence] += 1

# sentences_with_count contains values for all parts.
# Next step is to filter the ones counted in bigger terms

sentence_keys = list(sentences_with_count.keys())
for k in sentence_keys:
    for other in sentence_keys:
        if k in other and k != other:
            sentences_with_count.pop(k,None) # Remove consumed terms
            break

print(sentences_with_count)
```